# No output in console from std::cout in Visual Studio 2019 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, cout

I have some C++ executables which contain various std::cout outputs.
In Visual Studio 2019 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt, when I run these executables, there is no output displayed on the console.
If I redirect the output to a file, the output is indeed printed to the file.

The following program for example does not output anything to the console:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

Is there some setting or variable I need to set in order to see the output in the console itself ?

Comment: Can you try and also post a simple `std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;` program please.  See [mcve].

Comment: Are these GUI apps?

Comment: No they are not GUI apps.

Comment: What is your project type? If you rebuild your app does it change anything? And exactly what steps do you do to run the app?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "project type". Some example programs are supplied as part of a SDK. I build them within some SDK specific environment and then run the resulting executables. Note that I did the same thing on Visual Studio 2017 previously and the output was displayed in the console, so I don't think there is any specific setting in the SDK environment variables which is behind the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you provided, my console program can output normally.

[image]

I suggest you could verify that the Visual C++ developer command prompt is set up correctly. In the command prompt window, enter `cl` and verify that the output looks something like this:

[image]

For more details about how to compiling a Native C++ Program on the Command Line, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Walkthrough: Compiling a Native C++ Program on the Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @didjek Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.